# Using a template function return the size of an array

Tags: c++

I have come across this code snippet:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>  
char (&ArraySizeHelper(T (&array)[N]))[N];  
#define arraysize(array) (sizeof(ArraySizeHelper(array)))
```

I have also seen some other posts explaining it but one thing is still not cleared for me;

`char (&ArraySizeHelper(T (&array)[N]))[N];` is a declaration, where is the definition? How is it returning a value?

If I try to use `ArraySizeHelper` like a normal function I will get a linker error as it's not defined. Does `sizeof` not need a function definition?

Comment: Note that there is `std::size` for this in the standard library. No need to use that snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition is not needed as the function is not actually called. sizeof() only needs to determine what the type of the expression is and then calculate the size, it does not actually make the call.
just like if you had:

```
int foo();
size_t size{sizeof(foo())};
```

Remember that sizeof() is always evaluated at compile-time.

Answer (score 4):

Declarations in c++ must be read inside out, and right to left. This means `ArraySizeHelper` is actually a function template that accepts a `T(&)[N]`, and returns a `char(&)[N]`. Using trailing return type syntax makes this easier to read:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>  
auto ArraySizeHelper(T(&)[N]) -> char (&)[N];
```

I dropped the parameter name here since it's not needed anyway.

`sizeof` is then used to get the size in bytes of the `char(&)[N]`. Since `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1`, this effectively returns `N`. No function definition is needed, since `sizeof` doesn't actually evaluate its operand, it only determines the size.

The additional macro simply calls `sizeof`, thereby making the function even more confusing.

This function could be written a little more simply as:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>  
constexpr auto arrays(T(&)[N]) { return N; }
```